# how can I sort NSMutableDictionary with keys value?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsmutabledictionary

I have a `NSMutableDictionary` with string keys and every key has its own array. I want to re-sort the dictionary with keys value alphabetically. How can I do this?

Comment: i have unsorted NSMutableDictionary with key value and i want to re-sort same NSMutableDictionary with key values alphabetically. Is that possible with NSMutableDictionary?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

A dictionary is unsorted by definition.

For iterating over the keys in a specific order, you can sort an array containing the keys of the dictionary.

```
NSArray *keys = [theDictionary allKeys];
NSArray *sortedKeys = [keys sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compareMethod:)];
```

There are several other `sorted...` methods, e.g. sorting with a `NSComparator`. Have a look [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html).

Answer (score 8):

Use this one

```
NSArray *myKeys = [Dict allKeys];
NSArray *sortedKeys = [myKeys sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)];
NSMutableArray *sortedValues = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease];

for(id key in sortedKeys) {
    id object = [Dict objectForKey:key];
    [sortedValues addObject:object];
}
```

Comment: I used this code to retrieve sorted dictionary but still get it unsorted `code NSMutableDictionary *dicProjectListSorted = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    NSArray *sortedKeys = [keys sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];
    NSMutableArray *sortedValues = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease];
    
    for(id key in sortedKeys) {
        id object = [dicProjectList objectForKey:key];
        [sortedValues addObject:object];
        [dicProjectListSorted setObject:sortedValues forKey:key];
    }

Comment: from this code u get shorted key value and thn by key value u get your data

Comment: sortedKeys getting correct as sorted but when i try to recreate dictionary (dicProjectListSorted) inside a loop i get it unsorted??

Answer (score 3):

```
NSDictionary *yourDictionary;
NSArray *sortedKeys = [yourDictionary.allKeys sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"self" ascending:YES]]];
NSArray *sortedValues = [yourDictionary objectsForKeys:sortedKeys notFoundMarker:@""];
```

Comment: A worthy addition would be - that a Dictionary (whether mutable or immutable) maintains a hash table of its keys, and so - can never be really "sorted" - hence you MUST go through another collection object (here NSArray) which is ordered (maintains order of the items in the collection).