# How to set array value and key in NSDictionary in iphone?

Tags: iphone, ios, object, nsmutablearray, nsdictionary

Here i am using NSMutableArray to store date, then i tried to set key and assign ArrayValue in dictionary but the app crashed, please help me

Thanks in ADvance

```
 Here i tried the code for your reference:

  [DateArray addObject:dateString]; //NSMutablArray 
  NSMutableDictionary *myDictionary =[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];         
  [myDictionary setObject:DateArray forKey:@"Date"]; //put array value and set key in NSDictionary.
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

NSDictionary Class is immutable. You must convert to NSMutableDictionary.

Comment: Now i used NSMutableDictionary to store date fine, then How to sort this dictionary, is it possible?

Comment: refer a following q&a: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4558639/sort-an-nsmutabledictionary   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8118932/how-can-i-sort-nsmutabledictionary-with-keys-value

Comment: There isn't actually any need to use a mutable dictionary here, instead just use the appropriate `init` method or new syntax.

Answer (score 2):

You are using NSDictionary. You should use NSMutableDictionary.
NSDictionary is immutable. If you want to use NSDictionary then use below method:

```
- (id)initWithObjects:(NSArray *)objects forKeys:(NSArray *)keys;
```

Comment: Now i used NSMutableDictionary to store date fine, then How to sort this dictionary, is it possible?

Comment: dictionary can not be sorted. You can sort an array. Also you should accept my answer because I have given it before.

Comment: Your answer is pretty ambiguous. You have just given the method declaration without showing how to actually call it. This could very easily lead to any newbie using `[NSDictionary initWithObjects:....` as this is where the method is declared.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using XCode version 4.4 or later you can jus do this:

```
[dateArray addObject:dateString]; //NSMutablArray 
NSDictionary *myDictionary = @{ @"Date", dateArray };
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using an `NSDictionary` when you should be using `NSMutableDictionary`

Try this line :

```
NSMutableDictionary *myDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
```

Most of the collection classes in iOS have a mutable and nonmutable version (i.e.

```
NSArray -> NSMutableArray
NSSet -> NSMutableSet
NSDictionary -> NSMutableDictionary
(and others)
```

A mutable version will let you modify the contents. However, if you know you're not going to change it then a non mutable version will be slightly faster to use.

You can (usually) get a mutable class from a nonmutable one by using the `mutableCopy` method i.e.

```
// This array can't be changed
NSArray *myArray = @[ @"A", @"B", @"C" ];

// This array contains everything from the previous array but can now be modified
MSMutableArray myArray2 = [myArray mutableCopy];
```

NB : There are also other classes that have mutable subclasses i.e. `NSURL` -> `NSMutableURL`

Comment: check the question again before answering such a long answer.

Comment: Hang on, did you edit it and change the class names from immutable to mutable? __You've changed the question that is being asked__; do you know the original questioner? Edit is designed to make the question more correctly asked, not to 'fix' it - if you want to fix the code, answer the question!

Comment: Check out the name of Editor, don't blame me.

Answer (score -2):

Do it like this:

```
for(int i=0;i<[DateArray count]; i++)
{
   [myDictionary addObject:[DateArray objectAtIndex:i] forKey:@"Date"];
}
```

Comment: `myDictionary` isn't mutable - you can't call `addObject:forKey:` on it.