# how do I sort my NSMutableDictionary by the keys?

Tags: ios, sorting, nsmutabledictionary

I have a Dictionary

```
AlphaSite
BetaSite
GammaSite
```

I saw [how can I sort NSMutableDictionary with keys value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8118932/how-can-i-sort-nsmutabledictionary-with-keys-value) but didnt help me much

```
dictionaryOfWebsites = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[dictionaryOfWebsites setObject:@"http://www.site1.com" forKey:@"AlphaSite1"];
[dictionaryOfWebsites setObject:@"http://www.site2.com" forKey:@"GammaSite2"];
[dictionaryOfWebsites setObject:@"http://www.site3.com" forKey:@"ZetaSite3"];
[dictionaryOfWebsites setObject:@"http://www.site4.com" forKey:@"BetaSite4"];
```

I want to sort the Dictionary so my results are in alphabetical order (by keys)

Comment: And for the 1938462727th time: dictionaries are **still** unsorted.

Comment: We should put a feature request to sort dictionaries. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You better off just creating a quick class with 2 properties. Site and Url. Then you can just place them into an array and sort by Site. Like H2C03 said, dictionaries are not intended for sorting purposes.

Comment: I guess I'll have to add that later. First I'll make sure the app is "functional" before I start venturing into the great unknown