# Sort NSMutableDictionary Alphabetically by Key

Tags: objective-c

If I have an `NSMutableDictionary keys {B,A,D,C}` and `values {custom obj1, custom obj2, custom obj3, custom obj4}`,

I would like this to sort into

```
{A,B,C,D} -> {custom obj2, custom obj1, custom obj4, custom obj3}
```

Comment: You can't sort a dictionary. You can sort the keys and then access the objects based on the sorted keys.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how can I sort NSMutableDictionary with keys value?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8118932/how-can-i-sort-nsmutabledictionary-with-keys-value)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't sort dictionaries themselves. However you can get the key array `[dictionary allKeys]` and sort that. Something like:

```
NSMutableArray mutableKeys = [[dictionary allKeys] mutableCopy];
[mutableKeys desiredSortingMethod];
```

Comment: And yes, just now realized. It is a duplicate question.